# How to check if a cell is the 17th of any month

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, wildcard

I have a column of dates (daily) and I want an IF statement that will check if the corresponding cell is the 17th of any month.

I'm happy with the syntax of if statements but am unsure how I should be using wildcards here. 'x'below can be any numerical value. 
The cell in question looks like - 17/07/2019.

```
    = IF( cell = 17/**/****,x,0)
```

Excel gets confused and tries to show me how to do maths without a formula.

Comment: `=DAY(A1)=17` works perfectly, if you replace `A1` with your actual cell location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that the date is not a text value you can use a simple formula like:

```
=IF(DAY(A1)=17,”x”,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is that your dates may be genuine Excel dates or text values.  With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(DAY(A1)=17,"X",0),IF(LEFT(A1,2)="17","X",0))
```

[image]

Comment: For taking care of date as a text option in the same formula +1